# select distinct works on one table but not the other

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pdo

i have a bunch of tables in one database. i am using three for testing and have created the following sqls

```
SELECT DISTINCT bb_users.user_nickname FROM bb_users 
JOIN bucket_list ON bb_users.username = bucket_list.author 
WHERE bucket_list.status=(:s) ORDER BY bucket_list.author ASC LIMIT 0, 30
```

This returns the user_nickname from the bb_users table and works as expected

I then use the following to do so on a table named music

```
SELECT DISTINCT bb_users.user_nickname FROM bb_users 
JOIN music ON bb_users.username = music.author 
WHERE music.status=(:s) ORDER BY music.author ASC LIMIT 0, 30
```

i run the sql query with the prepared statement:

```
//$sql ->the sql statements from above
$prep=$conn->prepare($sql); 
$exec=$prep->execute(array(":s"=>"active"));  var_dump($exec);
while($fetch=$prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
   //do stuff
}
```

the music tables outputs nothing and using php PDO the execute method returns false

both of these lines of code are dynamically created so i am very confused as to how one works and the other does not

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Svengali You can put parentheses around any expression, it doesn't change the meaning.

Comment: Yes, the parentheses just make it easier for me to read

Comment: The query looks fine to me. Are you sure there are any users with active music?

Comment: It works in my sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87a9a9/1. Can you make a fiddle with sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: could you provide your database schema please?

Comment: @Barmar i adjusted the sqlfiddle at the link provided by you

Comment: What's the link to the adjusted version?

Comment: same as the one you made

Comment: @bushbrigade You have to provide the actual link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the collation code from utf8_unicode_ci to utf8_general_ci